# How to reformat ISO 8601 timestamps in UTC in time tags and same classes and adjust to user locale and timezone via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, timezone, momentjs

How to reformat ISO 8601 timestamps in UTC in time tags and same classes and adjust to user locale and timezone via JavaScript?

I do have a html page with a table with multiple timestamps in ISO 8601 Format in UTC enclosed in html time tags and given the same class.

I would like to reformat them to the users locale Format and timezone corrected.

I came up with the code below. What do I have to add like in the TODOs in the comments mentioned?

```
<!--- table with timestamps in ISO 8601 format and UTC --->
<table>
<tr><td>1: </td><td><time class="UTC_ISO_Date">2013-02-07T23:00:00.000Z</time></td></tr>
<tr><td>2: </td><td><time class="UTC_ISO_Date">2015-06-09T21:30:00.000Z</time></td></tr>
<tr><td>3: </td><td><time class="UTC_ISO_Date">2016-03-022T09:00:00.000Z</time></td></tr>
</table>

// get the timezone of the user out of the browser
var timezone = jstz.determine();
var usertz = timezone.name();

// TODO: get the locale of the user out of the browser    
// iterate over classes="UTC_ISO_Date" with each()
$('.UTC_ISO_Date').each(function(i, obj) {      
    // format the timestamps into the correspondent format of the user locale and adjust to the users timezone
    var formattedTimestamp = moment(i);
    // TODO: update the value in the current class

});
```

Comment: please add an example what you like to achieve.

Comment: Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for time and date manipulations.

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstimezonedetect/1.0.6/jstz.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.3/moment-timezone.js"></script>
I included Moment.js already but it's not shown.<

Comment: How do I update the timestamps to the users locale and timezones? How do I overwrite in the each() block the individual Dates?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the user's time zone for this scenario.  You don't need jsTimeZoneDetect, or moment-timezone.  You can simply call:

```
moment('2013-02-07T23:00:00.000Z').format()
```

You can pass parameters you want to the `format` function.  See the moment docs for details.

Also, most modern browsers will do this with the `Date` object, you just don't have as much control over the output format.

```
new Date('2013-02-07T23:00:00.000Z').toString()
```